# C++ Compiler picks wrong overload of output stream operator <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I have a very simple inline helper class called `IpAddress`, which has 2 overloads of operator << to either serialize an object to a set of custom binary streams (operator as template function) or to output it to a std::ostream (non-template operator function).

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef uint8_t byte;

class IpAddress: public std::array<byte,4>
{
    // ...

    template<class S>
    inline friend S& operator<<(S& left, const IpAddress& right) {
        left.setBytes(right.data(), 4);
        return left;
    }

    inline friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& left, const IpAddress& right) {
        // do stuff eligible for an ostream
        return left;
    }

    inline operator std::string() {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << *this;
        return stream.str();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is also an operator to convert the address to a string. Unfortunately, the << call inside is selecting the wrong operator<< (the template one), leading to a compiler error:

`error: C2039: 'setBytes' : is not a member of 'std::basic_stringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`

Why is the compiler (MSVC in this case) selecting the wrong overload with a non-working body? Why not the "more specialized" std::ostream operator? How do I change this behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: The standard containers are not really meant to be inherited (by e.g. not having virtual destructors), use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead. Another related article [about composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Also (and also unrelated to your problem) your design is flawed. Not only in regards to inheritance (is an IPv4 address really an array of *signed* bytes?) but also in that you forget to handle IPv6 addresses. If anything, you could have an abstract `IPAddress` base class, then from that have an inheritance tree with `IPv4Address` and `IPv6Address`. Then have a factory function that detects (some way) the correct type and creates the correct address object and returns it as a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Finally a minor nitpick... If you define member functions like that inside the class definition, they are `inline` by default so you don't need to specify that keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. As for the composition: I will change the structure accordingly. It is an array of _unsigned_ bytes. IPv4 is the only use case. I once had a problem with the linker complaining about multiple symbol definitions when using not explicitely declared inline functions from within different compilation units, so I started to just declare everything inline ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't post a complete, compilable example so I can't see the call site.

However, the problem is most likely because whatever you are streaming out to is not *exactly* an `ostream`. It's likely to be derived from an `ostream`. In which case, `template T` will be a better match.

EDIT:

Style comments aside (they are right and you would do well to listen), here is a fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>


template<class T> static constexpr bool IsAnOstream = std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<T>, std::ostream>::value;

using byte = std::uint8_t;

struct IpAddress: public std::array<byte,4>
{
    // ...

    template<class S, std::enable_if_t<not IsAnOstream<S>>* = nullptr>
    friend S& operator<<(S& left, const IpAddress& right) {
        left.setBytes(right.data(), 4);
        return left;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& left, const IpAddress& right) {
        // do stuff eligible for an ostream
        return left;
    }

    /* 
     * this is a bad idea - it can lead to all kinds of confusion
     *
    inline operator std::string() {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << *this;
        return stream.str();
    }
     */
};

// this is better - it's less surprising.
std::string to_string(const IpAddress& r)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << *this;
    return stream.str();
}


struct MyStream
{
    void setBytes(const uint8_t* p, size_t len) {}
};

int main()
{
    IpAddress a;
    MyStream s;

    std::cout << a;
    s << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the necessary includes/typedef, it should be compilable now.

Comment: Correct, it's  a ```stringstream``` in this case. Why is the template a better match? How can I use the ```ostream``` version instead?

Comment: @DevCybran updated with a fix which ought to get you going.

Comment: An example of a better match is that stringstream is derived from ostream, so considering the ostream overload requires 'one step of conversion' - to get from stringstream to ostream. However, template T can be anything - including a stringstream. This requires zero 'conversion steps'. Therefore T (when T is deduced to be stringstream) is a better match. Therefore the templated overload is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Due to compiler erros I transformed the conditional template to ```template<class S, std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<S>, std::ostream>::value)>* = nullptr>```. However, the ```stringstream``` still slips through :(

Comment: compiler? I tested mine on apple clang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107035/discussion-between-devcybran-and-richard-hodges).